# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress "ingress-nginx-admission" not found

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, raspberry-pi, kubernetes-ingress

I want to run a nginx ingress controller on a raspberry kubernetes.

Unfortunately I get the error message

```
 Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------       ----                ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    14m                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller-75557995f8-dz7hz to node1-pi4
  Warning  FailedMount  12m                 kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[webhook-cert], unattached volumes=[kube-api-access-7k4qh webhook-cert]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  81s (x5 over 10m)   kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[webhook-cert], unattached volumes=[webhook-cert kube-api-access-7k4qh]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  24s (x15 over 14m)  kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "webhook-cert" : secret "ingress-nginx-admission" not found
```

there are additional logs in the [github Issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/7043).
This version should be compatible with ARM CPU. I could not find any other information on setting up the this ingress controller on raspberry Pis.

Comment: The secret  `ingress-nginx-admission` is created?

Comment: It was running running but sometimes it restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure what exactly happened on your device. But I got a very similar issue. The solution may be helpful.

If you have tried multiple times to destroy the cluster, by `kubeadm reset`, without removing `cni0` device, `ingress-nginx-admission` pod won't be able to get created due to failure to connect API server.

Either deleting `cni0` device or simply restarting Pi device should remove such device successfully.

I would also check whether the following directories and files are deleted after running `kubeadm reset`

```sh
sudo rm -fr /etc/kubernetes/; sudo rm -fr /var/lib/etcd; sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cni/
sudo rm -fr /etc/cni/net.d
```